# Error processing purchase (BM-CPH-08) - Android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Some of my clients this issue while purchasing through google play. They got an error message `"Error processing purchase (BM-CPH-08)"` while trying to purchase.

This issue caused only for some users. For me its working fine, so I cant get the exact scenario of the issue.

What's the cause of the issue how can I solve it. Team please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What issue? Can you please elaborate !!

Comment: Please see my edited post. This issue caused only for some users. For me its working fine, so I cant get the exact scenario of the issue.

Comment: This is the issue with some of the phones or Google Play installed on them. its not with your app. So, you cannot do much for this. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a peculiar problem, only few experience this error. To fix this, follow the instructions.

1. Open Settings.
2. Tap Apps.
3. Look for Google Play store and tap it.
4. Tap Clear Data. 5. Tap Clear Cache.

If that did not worked maybe you need to update your Google Play Store to fix that version`s errors and bugs.

1. Open Settings.
2. Go to Security.
3. Put a check on Unknown Sources.
4. Now you need to download the latest Google Play http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/01/download-latest-google-play-store-4-4-22/
5. Download the APK file and put it on your phone`s SD card.
6. On your phone, open File manager.
7. Look for the Google Play Store APK and tap it to install.
8. Now you have an updated Google Play Store.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will forward these to my clients and will get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue when attempting to make a purchase from the Google Play store when connected as a hosted gmail/google account.

The problem was that the Google Wallet service had not been enabled for the user/org/domain that I was using to make the purchase.

I enabled the Google Wallet service by logging into the Admin Console as the main domain administrator[1] -> Other Google Services -> Change the filter if necessary, by unticking "Show top featured services" in order to show all services -> Google Wallet -> Click the drop down menu under the Shopping Cart icon and configure accordingly.

===================

[1] Note, I logged in originally as an organisation user who was also domain administrator, but for some reason they did not have full access to the Admin Console features. It was necessary that I logged in as the original domain administrator to see the "Other Google Services" console item

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occured because I was not logged in with a gmail ID in the phone.(My office mail was capable of using gmail services but not supported for making transaction)

Note:

If your app is not published, then add your tester email in the "Gmail accounts with testing access" field.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had a school google account linked to my phone in addition to a regular gmail account. Even though I made sure my google wallet, google play, and the game itself were linked to my regular account, apparently the fact that I had a school account (which doesn't allow transactions) linked to my phone made it so I could not make in game purchases.

What finally worked was going into settings/accounts/google on my phone and removing the school account. I then launched the game and was finally able to make a purchase. I then added the school account back on after the purchase and tried to make a purchase again and sure enough I got the same "google play error bm-cph-08" error message. So I will have to delete the account from my phone for every purchase I guess.

also, updating google play did nothing for me. I would look into your google accounts first.